# Configure Kafka to expose JMX only on 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, local, jmx, loopback

I'm struggling to configure Kafka's JMX to be exposed only on `localhost`. By default, when I start Kafka, it exposes three ports, whereas two of them are automatically bound to `0.0.0.0`, meaning that they're accessible to everyone.

I managed to bind the broker itself to `127.0.0.1` (because I only need it locally), but the JMX ports are really giving me headaches.

I have to following env vars defined:

```
export JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-9999}
export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

If I now look at the bound ports/ips, I see this:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 9864
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9864/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44895           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9864/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9092          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9864/java
```

meaning that JMX listens on `0.0.0.0`, and there's even another open port `44895` which I don't know its purpose.

What I'd like to achieve is that Kafka ports are only opened on `127.0.0.1`. Can anybody give a hint? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I was partially successful by adding `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=localhost`, but there's still one open port exposed on `0.0.0.0`:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 12789
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9999          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12789/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43513           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12789/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9092          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12789/java
```

Comment: can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/52397198/2442565

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just managed to make Kafka only listen to the defined broker port, and disabling JMX altogether:

```
export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

When starting a fresh Kafka 1.1.0 broker on Ubuntu, I initially saw two open ports:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 19894
tcp6       0      0 :::40487                :::*                    LISTEN      19894/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9092          :::*                    LISTEN      19894/java
```

After setting the above environment variable in the `kafka-server-start.sh` file, the second port is no longer opened:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep :9092
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9092          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20345/java
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 20345
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9092          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20345/java
```

Answer (score 0):

just

```
export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

is enough