# Not Able to see kafka.consumer and kafka.producer mBean in jConsole

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmx

**EDIT  : [I come to know t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799564/kafka-consumer-jmx-properties)hat I should enable JMX in my Consumer and Producer processes and get mBean info from respective processes.
How will i do this for a Java  process publishing message to Kafka and other Java processes consuming messages ?**

I have enabled JMX for Kafka . But still I cant see those two mBeans in jConsole.

I tried pub/sub onn Kafka broker but still no results .
My steps were as follows :
Added following in kafka-run-class.sh:

`KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.1.1 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`"

Added port in export JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-9999} in kafka-server-start.sh

[image: jCOnsole mBean screenshot]

Comment: You need to add java arguments to the Producer application if you want metrics from it. Producer and consumer metrics won't appear on the brokers

Comment: @cricket_007 I still dont have a Producer / Consumer application  . Just want to confirm if I shoudl add Java arguments in same kafka-run-class.sh file for Producer / Consumer or it will be some different file ?

Comment: You wouldn't use kafka-run-class to start either of those. It's typically just `java jar... options... app.jar` because you don't need Kafka files installed or available to run a producer or consumer application

Comment: @cricket_007 this is really helpful . will be in touch as I am working on Kafka these days .

Comment: @cricket_007 is there a way to enable JMX without restarting Kafka ? or should i create another thread?

Comment: Again, you wouldn't enable JMX on the Kafka server processes to get the information you're asking for, so no, you don't need to restart it

Comment: @cricket_007 i have a new question now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479009/alert-management-threshold-with-monitoring-for-kafka-confluent-jmx-metrics . Please have a look .

Comment: Hi @DivyanshuJimmy, I am also trying to configure Metrics for Kafka via JMX. I am using docker for Kafka and zookeeper. I need steps how to configure JMX for kafka. Can you please help me with that ?
TIA

Comment: @NIGAGA If you read my question again I have all steps there itself. for producer and consumerenable jmx int there respective processes using the configuration in my description .

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy, In your steps you have set the parameters on kafka broker and restarted the kafka-run-class.sh. And you have started the jconsole on broker itself. 
However, When I tried it, I have only setup the parameters on broker and restarted the broker. And Ran the jconsole on consumer side to get consumer metrics. 

Just want to check if I missed any step or doing it wrong all together. I am able to see the metrics correctly though.

Comment: @NIGAGA , you did it the right way !