# Alert Management Threshold with Monitoring for Kafka/Confluent JMX metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I am building an Alert Monitoring tool for Kafka.

I do understand that there can be metrics for which the thresholds depends on application data. But I am only interested in knowing those metrics and threshold values which will help me in knowing the lag and help in determining if any scaling is required.

As of now I can do following :

- Enable JMX on Kafka Broker
- Fecth JMX metrics using JMX Java client or jCOnsole.

Next I researched and found so many metrics but none had comnplete  thresholds (eg some value or pattern like increasing or decreasing or may be some maths ) over which I should write my logic for metrics .

Few Example are following :

UnderReplicatedPartitions - Alert if value is greater than 0.
records-lag-max - alert if value increases with time .
OfflinePartitionsCount - alert if value is greater then zero
ActiveControllerCount - alert if value other than 1 .

Comment: You realize Confluent Control Center can monitor and alert all of these already, yes?

Comment: @cricket_007 But Control center is part of licensed version .I have a requirement of building a custom solution in which monitoring Kafka is just one aspect .

Comment: Alright, well, I'm sure you could built some alerting platform with Grafana or Prometheus Alertmanager. Maybe something with  Kapacitor&Chronograf&InfluxDB